# I have a question, but I'm not sure where to ask it

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask the question below, but I'm not sure if SO is the right place.

> How can I create a new Skype emoticon?

Please indicate to me where I should open this question; and whether I should even ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super User has a [good collection of related questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skype) and a quick glance showed that your question probably isn't a duplicate. I suggest browsing through the Skype tag there just to be sure, then ask your question there.